# How to install npm packages in Atom?

Tags: wordpress, npm, atom-editor

I'm trying to add WordPress Coding Standards to ESLint in Atom. Unfortunately there are no package I could add via Atom's installer. I've found one (I think) suitable package [here](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/eslint-plugin-wordpress) but whenever I try to install it using Windows CMD or XAMPP shell I get "npm is ot recognized as internal or external command". I installed ESLint for Atom, so I've got the prerequisite met. Is it possible to add it to Atom on Windows at all?

Cheers, best regards.

Comment: Is `apm` in your `PATH`?

Comment: **@PradanaAumars** uuuum...is in my what? :) Don't really know what the PATH means...

Comment: **@PradanaAumars** Ok, I found out how to set a PATH on Windows in environmental variables but I have no idea what the PATH shoud look like? Is it a PATH to some kind app or executable inside of C:\users\USER\.atom folder?

Comment: One of the directories in your `PATH` variable should be `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\atom\bin`. This should allow you to use `apm`.

Comment: Ok, I set the path you pointed but the error remains. Plus it's npm not apm. Anyway I'm trying to install plugin for eslint via npm and after typing `$ npm install eslint-plugin-wordpress --save-dev` as the plugin docs state it gives me `'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` error.

Comment: Woops, I mistook `npm` for `apm`, my apologies. It should be `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm`. Also, you don't type `$` in a terminal, `$` is only used to denote that it is a command, for a terminal, nothing else.

Comment: Right, I didn't know about using `$` as pointing a command only. That's valuable information, still learning :) And nope, there is no folder such as `npm` in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\`. Shall I install anything or create that folder manually?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151544/discussion-between-pradana-aumars-and-daniel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

I digged into the topic and pparently I didn't have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed so I couldn't manage any npm packages. After installing Node.js I was able to install WordPress-Coding-Standards. Unfortunately I installed the wrong package at first, which was [eslint-plugin-wordpress](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/eslint-plugin-wordpress). After trying to set it up eslint started giving me plenty of errors. Then I found out (with a little help from guys on Github) that there are other WordPress Coding Standards plugin for eslint - [eslint-config-wordpress](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/eslint-config-wordpress) which I installed as well. Now everything works like a charm. It's good to learn something new everyday.

Thanks, Dan.

**EDIT**

Now above packages are deprecated, use [@wordpress/eslint-plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-eslint-plugin/)